# How cost function curve is actually calculated for gradient descent i:e how many times the model chooses the weights randomly?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, gradient-descent

As far as I know, to calculate the weights and bias for simple linear regression, it follows gradient descent algorithm which works on finding global minima for cost function(curve). And that cost function is calculated by randomly choosing a set of weights and then calculating mean error  on all the records. In that way we get a point on the cost curve. Again another set of weights are chosen and mean error is calculated. So all these points make up the cost curve.
My doubt is, how many times the weights are randomly chosen to get the points, before calculating (finding the cost function)the cost curve.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, initial parameters(weights) are chosen randomly only. After that, parameters(weights) are adjusted according to gradient descent algorithm(involves slope of cost function).

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: sorry for that @molbdnilo.I haven't read the description fully

Comment: Thank you for commenting @RishabhKumarSingh.As you said ,for adjusting the parameters ,slope of the cost function is needed.So cost function should be calculated before hand.For that some points are required (which are pairs of weights and the loss they resulted in predicting) b'coz with one point ,we can't draw curve.

Comment: So my doubt is how many such points are calculated (by choosing the weights randomly) for calculating the function of cost curve.I understood the gradient descent algorithm which comes after cost function calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Gradient descent algorithm iterates till convergence.

By convergence, it means, global minima is found out for the convex cost function.
There are basically two ways people use to find convergence.

1. Automatic convergence test :  Declare convergence if cost function decreases by less than `e` in an iteration, where `e` is some small value such as 10^-3. However, it is difficult to choose this threshold value in practice.
2. Plot cost function against iterations : Plotting cost function against iteration can give you fair idea about convergence. It can also be used for debugging (cost function must be decreasing on every iteration).

For example, in this figure I can deduce that I need near 300-400 iterations of Gradient Descent.

[image]

Also this enables you to check for different learning rate (alpha) vs iterations.

Comment: Next time wait at least 20 minutes :) it's a joke, nice job.